# Database Design - Storing n weeks data in database and update each week

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to show last four Sundays temperature for particular city, I need to update the database weekly (on Sundays)

#### Database Design 1

```
city_id     temp_pre_sunday1   temp_pre_sunday2   temp_pre_sunday3  temp_pre_sunday4  
1                  24.3              35.2           24.4             28.0                            
2                  4.0                2.0           6.0              7.0                  

 .
2000
```

I can update the database each Sunday. Is this good database design?

#### Database Design 2

```
 city_id      temp   date
   1          24.3    2017-12-03
   1          35.2    2017-11-26
   1          24.4    2017-11-19
   1          28.0    2017-11-12
   2          4.0     2017-12-03
   2          2.0     2017-11-26
   2          6.0     2017-11-19
   2          7.0     2017-11-12
   .
   .
```

**I need only four Sundays not more than that.**

I think first method is better, because  that way for 2000 cities **I will have 2000 rows and 5 columns**, in the second method **I will have 8000 rows and 3 columns**,

But in first method I need to update all the four columns,but in the second method I can maybe delete and insert one row.

Which is the better database design?

Comment: Database design 2 is the way to go.  There is no reason to delete rows.  Databases can easily handle tables with millions of rows, so your data is small.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thanks, But i am still confused, You mean i just keep inserting the data. Why I need to save data before 4 weeks, If I don't need that,

Comment: @user9050678. As soon as you delete the rows, the first statement on Monday morning of the fifth week will be "yeah but I need data from more than 4 weeks ago." Your users may tell you they only need 4 weeks but the minute you start deleting records, they will want them back. Like Gordon said, there's no harm to keeping the rows around. You'd be hard pressed to store enough weeks' worth of data to notice any performance degradation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database design 2 is the best way. You have more control and great flexibility to manipulate the data, to make reports, and extend applications etc...

Says, what if you want to fetch the 5 weeks data, or more, instead of 4 weeks? For database design 2 you only need to modify the query:

```
SELECT city_id, temp FROM table WHERE date >= _last_n_week_sunday_date_
```

Another things is, I may think you are creating a weather application, and trying to fetch the monthly average of temperature of each city, simpler query can get the report

```
SELECT city_id, YEAR(date), MONTH(date), AVG(temp) FROM table GROUP BY city_id, YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

You may also want to store more attributes later of each city, says humidity. You only need to create 1 more column for database design 2. Instead, you may need to do more hard work to work with database design 1.

Answer (score 1):

The way to evaluate "best" is complicated. But "number of rows" is almost never a problem in relational databases - they are specifically designed to handle huge numbers of rows.

A much more useful way to think about it is "what are the common things I want to do with the data".

I'm guessing you have a few use cases.

The first is "record new measurements". As you say, that's a little painful in design one.

The second is "find or report on measurements".

In design one, it's easy to answer questions like "what was the temperature in city x on the last Sunday?". But "what was the coldest temperature in the last 3 weeks" is harder. Or "what was the difference between the highest and lowest temperatures for city X?". If the number of weeks is passed in as a parameter, you end up constructing awkward queries. In design two, all of those queries are pretty straightforward.

That alone suggests that design 2 is better.

But as commenters have noted, requirements for databases tend to change. Most people think you have a good design if you can accommodate those changes by adding data, rather than changing your schema. So, if you need to store data for more than 4 Sundays, design 2 requires a schema change; design 1 doesn't. If you have to record data other than temperature, in design 1 you suddenly have multiple columns for each week; in design 2, you can simply add a "measurement_type" column (a much smaller change). So, it's likely that design 2 is more flexible in the face of change.